# PyDeadObjectError when deleting a panel with auitoolbar via the toolbar

Tags: python, wxpython, wxauitoolbar

I have a panel with auitoolbar in it and a 'delete' button on the toolbar. Pressing this button will delete the panel and everything in it. The problem is that beside `wx.EVT_TOOL` which I use to trigger the deletion, auitoolbar also triggers `OnLeftUp` event which happens after the panel was deleted, thus the `PyDeadObjectError`.
Is there any way around this?
Regular button works just fine, it's just a problem with auitoolbar.

```
python 2.7.2
wxpython 2.8.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `OnLeftUp` bound with `wx.EVT_LEFT_UP` event? If so, then on panel deletion you need also to explicitly unbind your panel with the event:

```
self.panel.Unbind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP)
```

Comment: I guess it is, but it is something internal in auitoolbar, and I can't unbind it no matter what I do.

Comment: Then, if you can't just unbind the `LEFT_UP` event from auitoolbar before panel deletion, you can subclass the `AuiToolBar` class, bind some method with `EVT_CLOSE`, and in that method unbind the `LEFT_UP` event.

Comment: After a bit of digging, it seems that all the functionality of a button press & release is handled in auitoolbar by `wx.EVT_LEFT_UP`, so maybe the only option is to use the same event for triggering the deletion.